# How do i parse this with DateTime.ParseExact?

Tags: c#, .net

Ive been reading up on how to use DateTime.ParseExact but i cant seem to figure out how to parse this:

December 16, 2018 08:00:00 UTC

Here is what i am doing currently:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(launch.windowstart, 
      "MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss \\G\\M\\Tzzz", 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the end of your format? `\\G\\M\\Tzzz` doesn't make sense at all with the value you're passing.

Comment: No idea. Ive been searching on here for how to parse it and one of them had that at the end,

Comment: You need to have an idea with `ParseExact`, because you need to be *exact*.. Give this a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Please make sure that your date time strings do not have different time-zone identifiers like PST,CST,etc... Otherwise, you will find yourself in a world of pain, as time zones offset are not necessarily constant over time (countries can change their time zone offsets basically on a whim). Also, daylight saving needs to be considered, with time zone identifiers possibly being used in an ambiguous manner sometimes. For example: `July 16, 2018 08:00:00 CET`. Note that this date is in the summer, so the time zone in effect should be CEST and not CET, but such ambiguities can happen sometimes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write a parser, but here is the code for it.

```
public static DateTime LLTimeToDateTime(string launchLibraryTime)
    {
        string[] segTime = launchLibraryTime.Split(' ');

        int monthLength = segTime[0].Length;

        int dayLength = segTime[1].Length - 1;

        string dateTimeFormatter = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < monthLength; i++)
        {
            dateTimeFormatter += "M";
        }

        dateTimeFormatter += " ";


        for (int i = 0; i < dayLength; i++)
        {
            dateTimeFormatter += "d";
        }

        dateTimeFormatter += ", yyyy HH:mm:ss";

        launchLibraryTime = launchLibraryTime.Substring(0, launchLibraryTime.Length - 4);

        return DateTime.ParseExact(launchLibraryTime, dateTimeFormatter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: I will say that while this may work, this could potentially be problematic if a string gets passed into this function without any spaces in it. You could probably write a regular expression to capture those certain values instead of hard-coded indexes. Have you tried the answer I gave? That might be a simpler solution to this particular problem than writing a parser for it.

Comment: This is specifically for an api i want to use so i know i will always get this exact match. Posted it just to give someone else an idea of what to do.

Comment: And yes i did try the one you gave, but it wasnt working (its because the month is a full string i think)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to modify your format string a bit. I'm not sure what that ending is for, but as Broots mentioned in the comments, you need to be exact with your formatting. It looks like you just need to modify the hour and the time zone capturing (in this case, UTC):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(launch.windowstart, 
  "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC", 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This should return the `DateTime` object I believe you're looking for.

Comment: Probably want `HH` instead of `hh` here, as this doesn't include AM/PM and HH captures 0-23

Comment: @NickDechiara Ah, you're right. Thank you. Fixing now.